# join query without association in Sequelize ORM framework

Tags: sequelize.js

Can I make join query without assocaition defined in Seuqelize?

I try to make sql query like below via Sequelize

```
SELECT * FROM MessageRecipient INNER JOIN MESSAGE ON MessageRecipient.messageIdno = MESSAGE.Idno
```

I did make it by using added "include" when using findAll like below and I have to defined the associations before I use include

Message.js

```
var Message = sequelize.define('Message', {
 idno: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true 
},
subject: DataTypes.STRING,
messageBody: DataTypes.STRING,
creatorId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
parentMessageId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
expiryDate:DataTypes.DATE,
isActive:DataTypes.INTEGER}, {
classMethods: {
  associate: function (models) { 
    Message.hasMany(models.MessageRecipient, { foreignKey: 'idno' });
  }}}); 
return ChatMessage;
};
```

messageRecipient.js

```
var MessageRecipient = sequelize.define('MessageRecipient', {
 idno: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  primaryKey: true,
  autoIncrement: true 
},
recipientId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
recipientGroupId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
messageId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
isRead:DataTypes.INTEGER
}, {
classMethods: {
  associate: function (models) { 
    MessageRecipient.belongsTo(models.Message, { foreignKey: 'messageId' });
  }
}
  }); return MessageRecipient;
```

findAll with include

```
db.MessageRecipient
      .findAll({
        include: [{
          model: db.Message,
          required: true
        }]
      })
      .then((MessageRecipients) => {
        res.json(MessageRecipients);
      })
      .error((error) => {
        res.sendStatus(500);
      });
```

And I would get the query result I want like below

```
[
  {
    "idno": 1,
    "recipientId": null,
    "recipientGroupId": 1,
    "messageId": 1,
    "isRead": 0,
    "createdAt": "2017-04-14T01:24:31.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2017-04-14T01:24:31.000Z",
    "ChatMessage": {
      "idno": 1,
      "subject": "my message subject",
      "messageBody": "my message content here",
      "creatorId": 1,
      "parentMessageId": 0,
      "expiryDate": null,
      "isActive": 1,
      "createdAt": "2017-04-14T01:24:30.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2017-04-14T01:24:30.000Z"
    }
  }
]
```

If I don't defined associations before findAll ,I will get error

```
Unhandled rejection Error: ChatMessage is not associated to ChatMessageRecipient!
```

How can I skip the hasmany,belong part and still get the pretty result like above?
Is there a workaround can make this?

Thanks

Comment: just wondering if you did find a way to achieve this?

Comment: @properchels not yet

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? Struggling with something similar now.

Comment: No. I don't use Seuqelize anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched through [the documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll) and found no way to specify the fields you join on. As far as I know, there is no way to do that with criteria queries. You either have to do separate (and inefficient) queries, either have to use raw queries:

```
sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM MessageRecipient INNER JOIN MESSAGE ON MessageRecipient.messageIdno = MESSAGE.Idno').then(([results, metadata]) => {
  // ...
})
```

This example comes from [the documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/raw-queries.html) too.